# Evernote Android API Broken? Intents to share documents no longer works

Tags: android, evernote

Our app uses the export to Evernote feature which as of now looks to be broken for our users. The issue is that the Evernote intent `com.evernote.action.CREATE_NEW_NOTE` no longer works and is currently throwing the exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.evernote.action.CREATE_NEW_NOTE typ=text/html

Our currently published app is no longer able to export documents to Evernote because of this error.

API Documentation says this should work: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/android_intents.php

Comment: Does this have to do with package visibility on Android 11?

Comment: Also happens on Android 10 after updating the Evernote app from 8.13.3 to 10.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new Evernote Android app doesn't support the `com.evernote.action.CREATE_NEW_NOTE` intent. However, it seems to support the default `ACTION_SEND` intent action and it's possible to create a new note by exporting a file with this intent.

Comment: I tried this on Android 11 and it does not seem to work. The target SDK version for our app is 29 so the package visibility should not affect this? Also, other functions like sending email that use the same intent ACTION_SEND do work.